# Neo4j LOAD CSV fails when multiline fields are encountered

Tags: neo4j

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ USING PERIODIC COMMIT
> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/ubuntu/data/woka-data/woka-data.csv" AS row
> MERGE (woka:Woka           {woka_id:        row.woka_id, woka_title: row.woka_title});
IllegalMultilineFieldException: At file:/home/ubuntu/data/woka-data/woka-data.csv:834 - Multi-line fields are illegal in this context and so this might suggest that there's a field with a start quote, but a missing end quote.
```

My kernel version is 2.2.3 and the file is quite large:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2508218727 Jul 21 17:54 woka-data.csv
```

Any clue how to fix this?

I changed the order of the fields in the file and now the first error is reported for line 83. Here is this line:

```
97801322605720000000,eng,Addison Wesley Longman,,"Wri& Speakg at Work& Build Own CC& Mst
: Perils"
```

It is a new line before

> : Perils

How to fix this?

This error seems to be specific to this kernel version.
Before upgrading I used a similar file to import the same data having multiline fields and it worked.

What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is still persistent in Kernel version 2.2.3 despite the claims that was fixed.
I had to clean all data at the extraction time. I removed all characters that caused LOAD CSV to fail with reported error message or similar.

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to import an Excel generated CSV file . I also tried to import the XLSX version of the same file using R (works) and then exporting it back to CSV (in case Excel's version was flawed). It still gives the same error.

Comment: Opened a new incident  in (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5028) as for whatever reason the fix was reverted, probably in 2.2.3 .

Answer (score 1):

Found this gem in the source code. See if any rows(lines) in your csv have illegal quoting. Escape these and try again

```
public class IllegalMultilineFieldException extends FormatException
{
    public IllegalMultilineFieldException( SourceTraceability source )
    {
        super( source, "Multi-line fields are illegal in this context and so this might suggest that " + "there's a field with a start quote, but a missing end quote." );
    }
}
```

This was an issue before Neo4j 2.2.2. Bug report can be found [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/4434).

If youre using any version previous to 2.2.2 update it and it should work

I am using Kernel version
Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel (neo4j-kernel), version: 2.2.3

Comment: There is no illegal quoting.

Comment: I understand. The `: Perils"` on the next line has the missing quote from the csv row

Comment: It was a bug, an update to Neo4j will fix it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am using this:Kernel version
Neo4j - Graph Database Kernel (neo4j-kernel), version: 2.2.3